# Is there a way to convert custom object and validate it in method signature after receiving it as POSTed JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring

I need to convert received `json` object to custom entity type `Product` and validate it. I need to persist it afterward. Is there a way to use annotation and Spring framework support for RESTful web services to do it with annotations and in controller's method signature only?

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class pController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public String addProduct(Model model, @Valid Product product , 
                                            BindingResult result){
                // somehow get converted json as Product, should be already validated
          }
```

**Entity**

```
@Table(name = "product")
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int product;
     @Column(name = "name")
     @Basic
     @NotEmpty
     private String name;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You want something that will have persisted the `Product` instance by the time you are in the controller handler method body?

Comment: I already have service to persist Product. I simply want validated Product to store.

Comment: Ah, then see the answer below. `@RequestBody` to deserialize JSON (and other types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that if you are using Spring version 3.1 or later. Just put `consumes` attribute in your `@RequestMapping` and providing `@RequestBody` before your `Product` parameter, like below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String addProduct(Model model, @RequestBody Product product , 
                                        BindingResult result){
            // you get your desired product object!
    }
```

**And most importantly**, put ***jackson*** as the dependency of your project.

- For xml based configuration you need `<mvc:annotation-driven />`
- For java based configuration just put `@EnableWebMvc` over your configuration class

And that's it!

**Edit:**

Yes, you have to use `@Valid` annotation before `@RequestBody`, because `@RequestBody` simply converts the Json to your expected Class object, it doesn't validate the object against your hibernate validation configuration. To do that, you have to put `@Valid` annotation together with `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Do I have to have `@Valid` before `@RequestBody`? Why?

Comment: @RCola, I have edited my answer to facilitate your question, please have a look.